# What's the first anime adapted from a galgame?

Tags: anime-history

There are many anime which are adapted from galgames now, e.g., *School Days*, *Kimi ga Nozomu Eien*, *Shuffle!* and so on.

What's the first anime adapted from a galgame?

Comment: I assume that "galgame" is a synonym for [eroge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eroge)? (Note: link contains NSFW images)

Comment: @F1Krazy Not necessarily, I think. I've not played a single one, though.

Comment: @F1Krazy a galgame can be an eroge, but it doesn't have to be. An eroge is a visual novel with sex scenes. A galgame is a visual novel where the objective is to get a girlfriend. The word gal is what you get if you write "girl" in Japanese (ガール) and read it back ga-h-ru → gal. It's short for "Girlfriend Game". The play style of a galge (even shorter form of the word) is to collect hidden affection points for the girl of your choice through choices you make. Once you've got enough for a certain girl you are on her "route" and depending on how many more points you can get the ending differ.

Comment: @Ocean I'm familiar with those sorts of games, just not the term "galgame", and Google didn't throw up any meaningful results so I didn't realise that that was what OP was referring to. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Anisearch](https://www.anisearch.com/anime/index) allows us to filter anime based on the type of material adapted.
[Using](https://www.anisearch.com/anime/index/page-1?char=all&adapted=102&sort=date&order=asc&view=1) the more general term of visual novel as a category, the 2-episode OVA *Rance* from 1993 seems to be the first anime adapted from such a medium.
This OVA is very loosely based on the erotic RPG series of the same [name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rance_(series)) (potential NSFW content).

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what is meant by galgame, but a web search suggests* [Dragon Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Knight_(video_game_series)) is one of the oldest. The game is released in 1989 and animated in 1991.

* [a source](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1047759045), you may not be able to see it depending on location

Answer (score 3):

As far as I remember, it was **To Heart (1999)** that established these kinds of anime on TV.

Technically both *Sentimental Journey (1998)* (based on Sentimental Graffiti) and *Night Walker (1998)* came earlier as far as TV anime based on a Visual Novel go. But not every VN is a Gal Game and I do not think either of these does qualify.

Same for Rance and Dragon Knight. They aren't really Gal Games. At least not if you think of a Gal Game as one where you are a guy trying to get a girlfriend among a selection of heroines through choices you make interacting with those heroines.

Comment: I don't really know the scene in those days, but it look like  [Tokimeki mememorial](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D%E3%82%81%E3%81%8D%E3%83%A1%E3%83%A2%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB#OVA) was OVA-ed in 1999, too.

Comment: @sundowner Tokimeki Memorial OVA released two months after To Heart.

Comment: I think SenGra is a gal game, esp. if you count Tokimemo. That being said, Pia Carrot 1 and 2 had OVAs before To Heart, if the 18+ versions counts.

Comment: @Jimmy I never read them so I cannot say, but based on the description SenGra doesn't look like a galge. Seems like a more linear experience where you don't have routes for each girl.

Comment: @Ocean SenGra is definitely a gal game. It is a love sim (or resource management, really) game, with the sequel been more of an adventure game. Multiple endings per heroin. In fact, it's more interactive than most gal games, which are just visual novels. (As much as I love the series though, the gameplay itself is kinda meh)